# Create a Global Session for all users

Tags: php, session-variables

I am using php 5.4
Session variables `$_SESSION['name']` are used to store data so that the data can be access in any future request but is unique to a user only

Is it possible to create something similar to a session variable which is accessible to all request coming in but no matter which user it is? In other words a session variable which is not unique to users

Currently I am using a MySQL db to store temporary data but I think if this `Global Session for all users` is possible, it will give some performance improvement
i want to store something very small like a 4 digit number

Comment: memcache, apc cache, simple file cache, just not with a superglobal

Comment: Session variables are "special" for who wisited your page. Session variables does not saving to Server-Side memory. You can set temporary data to your database and show it to your visitors.

Comment: @R.CanserYanbakan I am pretty sure data in a session variable is stored in the server's memory and its `id` is stored in a cookie in the user's browser for identification upon the next request

Comment: @Wrikken whats wrong with superglobals? Why do you say not to use it?

Comment: Do you mean something like a session but be available for all other active users?

Comment: @Javad Yes, Exactly that!

Comment: I think the value needs to be saved somewhere like DB then on any request from any user just put that value in your request header either a session cookie or new param in header

Comment: If you just need a common global that doesn't change, you can output your global with `var_export()` and then recall it at the beginning of your script (like call `session_start()`, just your own function): http://codepad.viper-7.com/phZ1MG You can, for instance, add that to the `$GLOBALS` array for superglobal functionality.

Comment: @Krimson: I'm not saying don't use superglobals, I'm saying there are a zillion reliable ways to do it it you don't need it to actually be a superglobal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default session data is `serialized` and saved to a temporary file associated with the user's session, which is tracked by a cookie.  You can configure session data to be saved in the database as well.  This data is available via the `$_SESSION` superglobal per user.

So if you follow that logic, then either store `serialized` data in a file or store it in the database and to access it, it won't be a superglobal, but something almost a superglobal if you read it in as a global array such as `$GLOBALS['all_peeps']`.

You can do the same with an object or static class.  It's really the same as config variables that you would use for your application regardless of the user.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!, Since sessions are stored in files anyways, Ill decide to store my data in files too.

Comment: Keep in mind: you need locking to avoid race conditions.

Answer (score 1):

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_%28computer_science%29):

**Session** is a semi-permanent interactive information interchange (...) between a computer and user.

Well, you probably missunderstand **session** meaning. Session shouldn't be global.

Anyway if you want some mechanism of sharing information between users,  you should use database or files (standard php session is stored in files [one for each instance]).

Comment: I suspect the OP understands without issue what session is and does.

Comment: thanks for your answer! +1 I didn't misunderstand session, I was just looking for something similar which was accessible to all users

Answer (score 0):

Sessions can't be and **shouldn't** be used as GLOBALs.

1. I am unable to understand why want to store a small number as 4-digit in a session var. I assume its a dynamic value (not static, which is why you aren't storing as a variable in one of your i.e. config files).
2. Best way to achieve that goal is to use MySQL... other alternatives are SQLite.
3. You can also achieve the same goal by storing that value in a local file.

to store value:

```
$fp = fopen("variable_name.txt", "w");
fwrite($fp, $value); // $value is the 4 digit value you wish to store.
fclose($fp);
```

to retrieve value:

```
$fp = fopen("variable_name.txt", "r");

$value = fread($fp, 1024);

fclose($fp);
```

if you could add more details / codes in question... it would be better.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in other answers session shouldn't be global. But why?

Reason: Web server is usually multi threaded. I.e. multiple requests are served at the same time. If one process writes to the global session and other reads at the same time, it might read incomplete data. ( And more serious things happens)

If you are using files to share common data and the data  may changes in requests, you should use operating system level locks on files. This is difficult and not recommended.

If you use database for the global season, 
If the session has only one piece of data, it should be fine as database will make sure there is no incomplete temporary state.
If the season has more than one piece of data and they are related to each other, you should use transaction features of the database to make sure they are in valid state in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be used as global variable, you may even make a kind of chat, using only session, but this is not the best approach. Just set the same session_id for each user